# Sending JSON object ios

Tags: ios, json, xcode

I'm new to iOS and looking for a little help. I am connecting to my socket server but having trouble emitting.

Heres how to emit:

```
if (self.socketIsConnected)
{
    [self.socket emit:(NSString HERE) args:@[(NSArray HERE)]];
}
```

Heres what I tried:

```
if (self.socketIsConnected)
{
    NSDictionary *deviceDic = @{@"username": @"drew", @"chatHash":@"FJHE8"};
    [self.socket emit:@"adduser" args:@[[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@", deviceDic]]];
}
```

The "args" param asks for a NSArray, but I need to send a JSON object that looks like this:

```
{"username": "drew", "chatHash":"FJHE8"}
```

How can I create this? And how do I put this object in the NSArray.

Update:

I tried this now

```
    NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"username", @"chatHash", nil];
    NSArray *objects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"drew", @"value2", nil];
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objects
                                                           forKeys:keys];
    [self.socket emit:@"adduser" args:dictionary];
```

and I looked on the server. It crashes my server with a throw exception. and the only data it receives is:

username

Comment: What is socket, which library class are you using ?

Comment: Library is SIOSocket. Just need help creating an json object the correct way though.

Comment: I think you need to flesh out a little on what the NSArray should look like.  Your JSON object resembles more of an NSDictionary.

Comment: If you need to send a JSON string then use NSJSONSerialization to serialize the dictionary into JSON.  Using stringWithFormat is definitely NOT what you should be doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you're using SIOSocket. The documentation isn't very clear but looking at the source for the emit function (https://github.com/MegaBits/SIOSocket/blob/master/SocketIO/Source/SIOSocket.m), all you need to do is pass an NSArray with the first parameter being an NSDictionary. The dictionary will be serialized as a JSON object by the framework.

You can have multiple arguments in the emit call. The type of each parameter in argument depends on the types of objects in the array you pass. If you pass a dictionary, it'll convert it to a JSON object, an array to an array, numbers as numbers, strings as strings.

Comment: Can you try replacing:  [self.socket emit:@"adduser" args:dictionary]; with:  [self.socket emit:@"adduser" args: @[dictionary]];

Comment: Well I did what k6sandeep told me to do and change the type that "args" is expected to be to a NSDictionary

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
     NSDictionary *subArgs = @{@"state" : @true};
     [self.socket emit:@"adduser" args:@[subArgs]];
```

This will solve the problem.